# Pass a table variable as a parameter to a table-valued function

Tags: sql, function, t-sql

Is it possible to pass a table variable as a parameter to a T-Sql table-valued function? I'd like to do something like the following (pseudo-code only):

```
SELECT FieldValue FROM udf_SplitString(SELECT EmpName FROM Employees)
```

where udf_SplitString is a table-valued function. I'm hoping to get as a result a table with the EmpName column from the Employees table, but with udf_SplitString applied to each EmpName. I don't want to use a table-valued parameter because I would have to create a UDF table type and this is just a one-time thing I'm doing.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What is the input to `udf_SplitString` now?

Comment: why not have the function in the select line and not the from line? ooo edit...D Stanley = speedy and beat me to it

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output? I would think that a SplitString on a name will give typically 2 rows, not two columns. Hence this request is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that `udf_SplitString` takes in a single value and returns a table.  If that's the case then I think you want:

```
SELECT ss.*
FROM Employees e
CROSS APPLY udf_SplitString(e.EmpName) AS ss
```

Comment: Thank you, D Stanley! Exactly what I was looking for.